# How to fix my viewArea so that it cannot be scolled or dragged in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to lock my ViewArea to one place in Anylogic? I dont want it to be moved or scrolled when I run the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Simulation properties and uncheck Window > Enable zoom and panning

[image]